# hibernate throwing multiple errors at a time

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am a newbie in hibernate and I was trying to implement an application which could create a table on its own using hbm2ddl mapping but my Java application is throwing multiple errors at once.

//Main Class

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
        Teacher teacher=new Teacher();
        teacher.setName("abc");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(teacher);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }

}
```

//POJO Class

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="xyz")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @Column(name="name")
    String name;

    @Column(name="subject1")
    String Subject1;

    @Column(name="subject2")
    String Subject2;

    @Column(name="subject3")
    String Subject3;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSubject1() {
        return Subject1;
    }
    public void setSubject1(String subject1) {
        Subject1 = subject1;
    }
    public String getSubject2() {
        return Subject2;
    }
    public void setSubject2(String subject2) {
        Subject2 = subject2;
    }
    public String getSubject3() {
        return Subject3;
    }
    public void setSubject3(String subject3) {
        Subject3 = subject3;
    }
}
```

//hibernate.cfg.xml(I tried using hbm2dll.auto instead of hibernate.hbm2dll.auto but that also didn't work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      aayushiDB
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      password
   </property>
   <property name="show_sql">true</property>

   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping class="Teacher"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The error log file that I am getting for the above application is--

```
//error log

Apr 05, 2017 1:25:24 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:24 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:25 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/test]
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=aayushiDB, password=****}
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Wed Apr 05 01:25:26 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:26 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:26 AM org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl configure
INFO: Envers integration enabled? : true
Hibernate: drop table if exists xyz
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:26 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@4218500f] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create table xyz (name varchar(255) not null, subject1 varchar(255), subject2 varchar(255), subject3 varchar(255), primary key (name)) type=MyISAM
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:26 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@4233e892] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:26 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:12)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2497)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2455)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 13 more

Apr 05, 2017 1:25:26 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@319bc845'
Hibernate: insert into xyz (subject1, subject2, subject3, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Table 'test.xyz' doesn't exist
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Apr 05, 2017 1:25:27 AM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]
```

Comment: Try using InnoDB by specifying `<property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
   </property>`

Comment: Best way to debug hibernate issues is by executing the generated SQL directly on the MySQL console. In your logs, you can find a line like `Hibernate: create table xyz (name varchar(255) not null, subject1 varchar(255), subject2 varchar(255), subject3 varchar(255), primary key (name)) type=MyISAM` Try executing it and see what is the problem. May be your version of MySQL does not support MyIASM engine.

Comment: I have installed the latest version of mysql.And the part type=MYISAM is getting added to the query on its own.So, how do I resolve that. Is that some library version issue?? @prasanth